# Drawing bezier curve using four segments

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to draw a bezier curve which uses 4 control points to draw a curve. However when I run my program, after 4 clicks with mouse I only see one pixel being drawn, am I missing something in my code? How can I get this to work properly?

```cpp
void MyWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        x0 = event->x();
        y0 = event->y();

        point.setX(x0);
        point.setY(y0);
        std::vector<QPoint> myv;
        myv.push_back(point);
        counter+=1;
        std::cout<<counter<<std::endl;

        if(counter%4==0) {
            drawBezier(myv[0], myv[1], myv[2], myv[3]);
        }
      
    }

    update();

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myv` is local variable and you dont save its state to the new `mousePressEvent`
Get some "debug" info and see what you receive in `drawBezier` function.

Comment: thanks, that solved my issue. However by any chance, do you might know how can I keep drawing the line from the last 4th point? I've pressed four times on my screen and the curve has been drawn, but how can I continue drawing with next points?

Comment: Just take the last four point from your `myv` vector.